# How to setup Logging in PlayFramework for external jar

Tags: logging, jar, playframework, slf4j

I'm using Play! Framework 2.2.x that includes a Jar-File in its lib directory, which should perform logging, but shall not depend on play.Logger but only on SLF4J. 
Unforunately I cannot find anything about this problem neither in Play documentation nor on StackOverflow.

In the external Jar file, SLF4J is used like in the SLF4J Manual:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloWorld {
  public void test() {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Please help me out - any hints how to solve this?
Thanks in advance,
Manfred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play is using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as its logging system. If I am not mistaken, the SLF4J bindings are already provided in Play, so any library relying on SLF4J should be working. You can check how to configure things [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger)

Comment: Hi Manuel. Thanks for the information - you are right. It did not work because Play! (2.2.x) sets the root logger in file _conf/application.conf_ to level ERROR as default - but the loggings are done in level INFO. So changing the root logger level was enough to solve the problem.